# how to fetch the data from php web file to objective C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I've been stuck on this problem for a while so i would really appreciate some help. I am very new with iOS app programming. I have started with login app but i am facing some problem in getting the "login successful status" while fetching response from php file. I just getting **"signin failed"**. I am going to give u my code. Pls rectify my mistake.
                               **(ViewController.m )file code//**

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "SBJson.h"
    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    -(IBAction)signinclicked:(id)sender
    {

    NSInteger success=0;
    @try {

        if([[self.txtusername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtpassword text]                 isEqualToString:@""] ) {

            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];



          } else {

            NSString *post =[[NSString  alloc]initWithFormat:@"username=%@ & password=%@",         [self.txtusername text],[self.txtpassword text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shiv.9gem.net/alka/index1.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding    allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)                    [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);


                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];

                success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }

            } else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }
    if (success) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}

    - (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
    {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
    }
  - (IBAction)backgroundtap:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end

                             ***( php file code)***


    <?php
    header('content-type:application/json');
    $dbhost = 'localhost';

    $dbuser = 'shiv9gem_alka';

    $dbpass = 'alankritasharma';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(!$conn )

    {

     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    $sql = 'SELECT username,password FROM student';



    mysql_select_db('shiv9gem_project');

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval )

    {

    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))

    {


    echo json_encode($row);
    } 

    echo "Fetched data successfully\n";



    if($_POST)
    {
    if($_POST['username']=='alankrita' && $_POST['password']=='isha123')
    {
    echo '{"success":1}';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"username and/or password is invalid."}';
    }
    } else
    {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"username and/or password is invalid."}'; }
    mysql_close($conn);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see some bad practices in your code like not making asynchronously request or not separating server request layer from controller layer.

Leave behind this, I recommend you read about Model View Controller pattern (Understanding this pattern: http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

Some that can help you implementing request layer is RestKit (http://restkit.org/) wich is a framework for iOS that aims to make interacting with RESTful web services. You can check this useful tutorial from RyanWenderlich website http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i will try your suggestion definitely.